# GetWindowRect returns odd values

Tags: c#, wpf, winapi, pinvoke

I hope that someone will be able to help me with this, I have the following bit of code in my application in a method to get me a Rect

```
var windowPosition = NativeMethods.GetWindowRect(this._hwnd);
return new Rect(windowPosition.Left, windowPosition.Top, windowPosition.Width, windowPosition.Height);
```

I am using this in some code that I have written for a custom window and this is in a WPF application, the window is opened using the `IWindowManager.OpenWindow`.

When I run the code and open the window I am getting the following values in the `windowPosition` object which is a RECT

```
top = 1466, bottom = 785, left = 26, right = 26, width = 0, height = -681
```

I cannot see what is wrong in the code that would end up with these odd values in the RECT, and I get an `ArgumentException` in the next line as a result.

I have also tried running this window as the main application window and I am getting the same problem, the application is using MVVM and Caliburn Micro although im not sure why that should make a difference.

As requested the RECT struct is defined as below:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
internal struct RECT
{
    public void Offset(int dx, int dy)
    {
        this.Left += dx;
        this.Top += dy;
        this.Right += dx;
        this.Bottom += dy;
    }

    public int Left { get; set; }

    public int Top { get; set; }

    public int Right { get; set; }

    public int Bottom { get; set; }

    public int Width
    {
        get
        {
            return this.Right - this.Left;
        }
    }

    public int Height
    {
        get
        {
            return this.Bottom - this.Top;
        }
    }

    public POINT Position
    {
        get
        {
            return new POINT { x = this.Left, y = this.Top };
        }
    }

    public SIZE Size
    {
        get
        {
            return new SIZE { cx = this.Width, cy = this.Height };
        }
    }
}
```

and the GetWindowRect method from NativeMethods:

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "GetWindowRect", SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    private static extern bool GetWindowRectInternal(IntPtr hWnd, out RECT lpRect);

    public static RECT GetWindowRect(IntPtr hwnd)
    {
        RECT rc;
        if (!GetWindowRectInternal(hwnd, out rc))
        {
            throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
        }
        return rc;
    }
```

I am accessing `hWnd` using `WindowInteropHelper(window).Handle`, I neglected to include the public method from NativeMethods and have included that now, apologies for wasted time.

Comment: RECT doesn't have a width or height property, significantly increases the odds you just declared it wrong.  Strange you did not post relevant code.

Comment: show us how you have GetWindowRect and your RECT structure defined.

Comment: It's let-top-right-bottom, and not left-right-top-bottom.

Comment: I will change that tonight and give it a try, but why would that make a difference?

Comment: Something's not right with what you are quoting for us here: Your call to `NativeMethods.GetWindowRect` at the top returns something that has `left`, `top`... properties - a `RECT`, presumably. Yet your import declaration (correctly) states that `GetWindowRect` returns a `bool`.

Comment: You posted faked code. That's a huge waste of time. Please post a [mcve].

Comment: @500-InternalServerError the public call in NativeMethods simply wraps the API call gets the last error if it returns `false`, this method returns the RECT

Comment: Now you've got code that doesn't check for errors. Where is that [mcve]?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I have not written the code to check for errors yet which is why there is the `// TODO` comment

Comment: And it doesn't bother you that the function could be failing and you don't know whether or not it is? Why won't you show a [mcve]?

Comment: And you've still got right and top reversed.

Comment: Corrected the RECT structure as suggested and tested in my application, this does resolve the problem but would like to understand why that makes a difference, have also correct the "fake" code. Also, the comments about posting fake code, I have tried to extract the relevant parts from my application which has a lot of other code that is not relevant to this problem, it was never my intention to post "fake" code so I take the point and lesson learnt for the next post.

Comment: Neil, you used (perhaps copy/pasted from somehwere) "Sequential" word in your code, to emphasize the order of declaration is important. [Read on up on this on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.layoutkind) to get better understanding.

Answer (score 5):

As has been pointed out several times by various commenters, your `RECT` structure has its members declared in the wrong order. The [Win32 `RECT` structure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162897.aspx) defines a rectangle by its `left`, `top`, `right`, and `bottom` bounds. The right and bottom bounds lie just outside of the rectangle (in other words, a rectangle is [end-point exclusive](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040218-00/?p=40563)).

Therefore, you need to fix your structure definition:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct RECT
{
   // Data members, in order, matching the Win32 RECT structure:
   public int Left;
   public int Top;
   public int Right;
   public int Bottom;

   // Constructor:
   public RECT(int left, int top, int right, int bottom)
   {
     this.Left  = left;
     this.Top   = top;
     this.Right = right;
     this.Bottom = bottom;
   }

   // Convenience properties:

   public int Width
   {
     get  { return this.Right - this.Left; }
     set  { this.Right = value + this.Left; }
   }

   public int Height
   {
     get  { return this.Bottom - this.Top; }
     set  { this.Bottom = value + this.Top; }
   }

   // Conversion helper functions:    

  public System.Drawing.Point Position
  {
     get  { return new System.Drawing.Point(this.Left, this.Top); }
  }

  public System.Drawing.Size Size
  {
     get  { return new System.Drawing.Size(this.Width, this.Height); }
  }
}
```

You also need to ensure that your `POINT` and `SIZE` structures are correctly defined. Or, since the `System.Drawing.Point` and `System.Drawing.Size` structures are 100% compatible with the native types, just use those instead (as the conversion functions in the above `RECT` struct do).

It is worth pointing out the existence of a website called [pinvoke.net](http://www.pinvoke.net/), which is a collaboratively-edited (wiki-style) repository of P/Invoke signatures—both for structures and functions. In the early days, the definitions weren't entirely trustworthy, but I think they're getting better. (I stopped writing these a few years ago and haven't kept up with the site's progress. At least its [RECT structure](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Structures/rect.html) is correct.)

Your P/Invoke definition for the `GetWindowRect` structure is correct, but the code you've shown won't compile. There is no `GetWindowRectInternal` function. You need something like this instead:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true, EntryPoint="GetWindowRect")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
private static extern bool GetWindowRectInternal(IntPtr hWnd, out RECT lpRect);

public static RECT GetWindowRect(IntPtr hWnd)
{
    RECT rc;
    if (!GetWindowRectInternal(hWnd, out rc))
    {
        throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
    }
    return rc;
}
```

Comment: Realised I had typo in the code I posted so have corrected that, and have corrected my RECT definition, would like to understand why the position of the four properties matters?

Comment: You are doing interop with native code, @Neil. The Win32 functions that you're calling (like `GetWindowRect`) expect to deal with a `RECT` structure. That's how they were written, and it is part of their ABI. The `RECT` structure is defined a certain way, with its members in a certain order. If you define a different structure, with its members in a different order, and pass it to those functions, they won't know they've been tricked. They'll treat it like a `RECT` structure, but it won't really be one, so you'll get the wrong results. It's like prank-calling someone.

Comment: Notice how the structure here is declared `[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]`. That keeps the compiler from rearranging the order of the members, and reminds you that the order matters.